# Salesforce Data Extension clarification

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

In order for email tracking to be sent back to Sales Cloud from an email studio send, the Data Extension used for sending should be a Salesforce Data Extension, correct?

Filtered Synchronized data extensions are not considered Salesforce data extensions in the context of email tracking back to Sales Cloud?

Salesforce data extensions are only created from reports via import?

Those are my main questions that will help to clarify my understanding of Salesforce data extensions and email tracking to Sales Cloud.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

good questions:

> In order for email tracking to be sent back to Sales Cloud from an email studio send, the Data Extension used for sending should be a Salesforce Data Extension, correct?

correct

> Filtered Synchronized data extensions are not considered Salesforce data extensions in the context of email tracking back to Sales Cloud?

not by design, but easy to fix:

> Salesforce data extensions are only created from reports via import?

incorrect. Just move your filtered Data Extension into the Salesforce Data extensions folder and it becomes one. This would work also for other data extensions, but with a filtered synchronized DE you are sure that you have a Contact / Lead ID as Subscriber key in the DE to send back tracking.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Jonas, that does help!